# Using Paging 3 with two different requests so it works bidirectionally

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

I have this task to do and it seems a bit like it might not be possible, at least with Paging 3 (and I don't know what else can be used for paging besides this library).

The thing is, I have this recycler view with some events that are paginated when you scroll down. That works well but I also have the option to move to another day to get events (through a day picker) that triggers a new request to the backend to load events from that day on. That also works okay. The problem is, I need to be able to scroll up when I change the date in the day picker so I can get the newer events (if I'm in the day 10, I'd need to get the events till the day 14, today, but upwards) while also being able to scroll down and continue with the pagination that consults the same endpoint with different parameters.

Basically, I need to be able to keep the paging working bidirectionally with requests that take different parameters so I can get older and newer events when scrolling down/up. I did try to intercept the scroll up and call the fetchEvents() again with the different parameters but that invalidates the request that was working downwards so now I can only scroll up.

Is there a way to achieve this with Paging 3? Or is there some other library that allows this? I'm really lost.

Fragment's method (If I'm in date "today", then the dateTo gets filled. If I'm in date 13, two days before, and it hadn't loaded, then dateStart gets filled. If I want to go up from that other date, dateFrom and dateTo get filled. When that happens, I need to be able to keep the two requests alive so that I can scroll up and get newer events but also down to get older events in the same recycler view).

```
 private fun getEvents() {
    getEventsJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        myViewModel.searchEvents(
            dateTo = if (eventsByDate) "" else dayPickerTo,
            dateStart = if (eventsByDate) dayPickerStart else "",
            dateFrom = if (eventsBefore) dayPickerFrom else "",
        ).collectLatest { eventsCollection ->
            val events = eventsCollection.map { event ->
                specialEventsModel.eventItem(
                    eventModel(
                        event.eventId,
                        event.eventType,
                        event.eventDate
                    )
                )
            }
            binding.eventsRecycler.adapter = eventsAdapter
            eventsAdapter.submitData(events)
        }
    }
}
```

Paging source:

class EventsDataSource(
private val service: eventsService,
private val dateTo: String,
private val dateStart: String?,
private val dateFrom: String?
) : PagingSource<Int, specialEvents>() {

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, specialEvents> {
    val pageIndex = params.key ?: 1
    return runCatching {
        service.getspecialEvents(
                dateTo = this.dateTo,
                dateStart= this.dateJump,
                dateFrom = this.dateFrom
            )
      
    }.fold(
        onFailure = { LoadResult.Error(it) },
        onSuccess = {
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = it.eventsData.specialEvents,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = if (it.eventsData.specialEvents.isNotEmpty()) pageIndex + 1 else null
            )
        }
    )
}

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, specialEvents>): Int? {
    return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
        val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
        anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
    }
}
```

If there's another way to do this, I'm all ears. But, basically, I have 3 different requests I can make to the backend to get data from "today", the day selected in the day picker, and when going up from the selected day in the day picker to data that has not loaded yet. If there's a way to solve this through the backend, I'm also open to proposals.

Comment: Paging already supports both prepending data to the beginning of the list and appending data to your list automatically as you continue to scroll in either direction, as well as jumping to a specific point in your list, re-centering the user's view (ala your day picker). How are you building your `PagingSource`? How are you jumping down to a selected page? Please show your code.

Comment: I added the code. But, to clarify, when I go to another day, it loads from the beginning, taking that as page 0 and then 1, 2, 3, etc, as it goes down. And, if I go up from that day on, it's up from 0 and then 1, 2, 3, but in the other direction. So we have a 0 that starts counting up and down the same way from to different endpoints. I hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: If you set your `prevKey` to `null`, how are you expecting to be able to prepend data (i.e., scroll up to load more data)?

Comment: But how can I prepend data that can be added through another request to the backend that starts counting upwards? It's not like I'm going minus 1, I need to start counting upwards while keeping the count downwards with the other request